# tinyMCE aborts with "Object doesn't support this action".

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

I'm trying to use the AngularJS directive ui-tinymce with tinyMce 4.0.25 and IE10, and am unable to get it to work at all.

My html looks like this:

```
<textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="fubar"></textarea>
```

In my controller, I have:

```
$scope.fubar = "this is a <b>test</b>";
```

It all goes badly at these two lines in the tinymce initialization code itself.

```
Theme = ThemeManager.get(settings.theme);                   
self.theme = new Theme(self, ThemeManager.urls[settings.theme]);
```

The first line sets Theme to undefined and the last line aborts with the message "Object doesn't support this action".  The value of `ThemeManager.urls[settings.theme]` is `"http://localhost:57683/Scripts/tinymce/themes/modern"`, which seems right.

I can no longer find it, but I'd previously found a post where this issue was due to this code being executed before some other part of tinyMCE had been loaded. The solution there was to use a certain tinyMCE option that forced loading in a certain way, however that option has been removed in tinyMCE 4.x. Even more frustrating is that I had tinyMCE working for days with my own directive when suddenly this occurred. I've simplified this to just using ui-tinymce (with the same result) to rule out any of my code as the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa! I'd switched to using tinymce.js instead of tinymce.min.js and didn't realize that the min code expects the theme to be modern/theme.min.js (which I had) but the unminified code expects the theme to be modern/theme.js.